# JavaFX: Stages are empty

Tags: javafx

I am facing a strange problem: When running my application everything works fine, the code compiles, the debugger shows that everything is in order but stages different to the primary stage do not show their continent, they appear just empty white.

I cannot provide a reproducible code sample because it works on my other system just OK.

So my question is: What could cause the stages not to display their content?

I am using JavaFX 11 with ZuluFX 11.

**UPDATE:** I just tried to run version which was built on a system where the displaying works and I have the same effect: Empty windows.

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: some setup weirdness in your system, maybe? Vey unlikely that anybody can help you from afar, I'm afraid ..

Comment: That's what I thought. I never had this before and I don't think that it is down to the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without further information, but try to start the application with `-Djavafx.verbose=true -Dprism.verbose=true` and check if you get some error message which might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, using SW rendering works fine. I am not sure how large the impact of SW rendering is.